# What do field lines between two like-charged parallel plates look like?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields

I couldn't find any image to answer my question on Google.

But I guess it looks somewhat like this, correct?
[image]

Comment: Good stuff user. Now ask a question about drawing _electromagnetic_ field lines for a single particle.

Comment: If the plates are conductive the charge distribution would be unequal, with most of the charge at the ends of the plates. If they are insulating, your drawing roughly shows what happens in between (which is what you asked). There will also be field lines outside.

Comment: @Floris, I would much appreciate if you could attach a link, or make a diagram of field lines outside.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is correct. Also there are field lines going out from the top of the top plate and the bottom of the bottom plate. And far away, the field lines should look like those of a single point charge, with charge equal to the total charge on the two plates.

Comment: Here's a diagram of two like point charges in close proximity: http://cnx.org/resources/0de6d19179e1071a9ace9d38b30f74db1c2c8c23/Figure_20_04_05a.jpg

Comment: Do you mind uploading a diagram?